# Decrementing row count with Laravel pagination (not Incrementing)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display the row count of a `decrementing` paginated collection in Laravel,
I have searched a lot, and there are methods to do it incrementing order, but not decrementing.

#### Explaining the issue:

Using Laravel 8.x, I have a controller method like this (simplified):

```
public function page(){
    // Please note the orderBy('id','DESC')
    $info = ModelName::where('something','value')->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
    return view('page', compact('info'));
}
```

In my view, I display the data in a table like this

```
<tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
@foreach($info as $item)
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $info->firstItem() + $loop->index; }}</td> /* <--- This is where I need help */
      <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

And finally the pagination links

```
{{ $info->links() }}
```

Currently, even though I have a `orderBy('id','DESC')` and the first result in table is actually the last data, I am displaying the row count (#) in table like this:

Page 1:

```
------------------------------
|  #   |         Name        |
------------------------------
|   1  |        Value J      |
|   2  |        Value I      |
|   3  |        Value H      |
|   4  |        Value G      |
|   5  |        Value F      |
------------------------------
```

Page 2:

```
------------------------------
|  #   |         Name        |
------------------------------
|   6  |        Value E      |
|   7  |        Value D      |
|   8  |        Value C      |
|   9  |        Value B      |
|  10  |        Value A      |
------------------------------
```

#### But what I want to do is to display the row count in reverse

Because first result displayed is actually the last result (`orderBy('id','DESC')`).

Like this:

Page 1:

```
------------------------------
|  #   |         Name        |
------------------------------
|  10  |        Value J      |
|   9  |        Value I      |
|   8  |        Value H      |
|   7  |        Value G      |
|   6  |        Value F      |
------------------------------
```

Page 2:

```
------------------------------
|  #   |         Name        |
------------------------------
|   5  |        Value E      |
|   4  |        Value D      |
|   3  |        Value C      |
|   2  |        Value B      |
|   1  |        Value A      |
------------------------------
```

How can I achieve this?

P.S. I cannot just use the ID, as there are gaps in between results because of the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case any one else needs to do this, here is the solution:

```
{{ ($info->total() - ($info->firstItem() + $loop->index)) + 1 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply calculate the differentiate between the total number of items and the index.

```php
{{ $info->firstItem() + ($info->count() - $loop->index) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now on the first page I get: `6,5,4,3,2,1` and on the second page `11,10,9,8,7`

Comment: But your answer helped me get the idea, I just figured it out: `{{ ($info->total() - ($info->firstItem() + $loop->index)) + 1 }}` Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but still getting `5 > 4 > 3 > 2 > 1 > 10 > 9 > 8 > 7 > 6 > 5 > 12 > 11`, guess I should just use the way I found, even though it doesn't seem like a clean solution.